# Is there possible to have "submit" and "cancel" button at toolbar kendo ui grid?

Tags: button, kendo-grid

I want to create at toolbar only "submit" and "cancel" buton only . Do not need to "add new record" because i have treeview within checkboxex. So, the "submit" can fetch the id of checkboxes selected and also other data. Or is that easier with using normal button "submit" and do ajax call function? I'm a little bit confused here.[image: There the ouput that i can show to you]

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such toolbar control but you may create and design same like this in HTML.

Comment: If i use normal button like html, what the best way to do the function? Do i need to built the ajax call and how?

Comment: It depends on your requirement, you can use ajax call if you avoid refresh page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any number of button in the toolbar section as folllowing.. but we havr to handle the event using onclick as follows

```
 .ToolBar(toolbar =>
  {
       toolbar.Excel();
       toolbar.Custom()
       .HtmlAttributes(new {onclick="Submit();returnfalse;" })
       .Name("Submit").Text("Submit").Url("#");

        toolbar.Custom()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "Cancel(); return false;" })
        .Name("Cancel").Text("Cancel").Url("#");

    })
```